# find and replace unicode character 0x1a

Tags: php, unicode, editor, salesforce

I got error:" PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Client] An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the element content of the document."

How to search which value contains this 01xa character? in PHP or in some text editor?

Tried this one, but not working...

```
$test = strstr($value, '\u001a');
    if($test){
        echo $test;
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Try `strstr(utf8_decode($value), utf8_decode('\u001a'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for \u001a using regular expressions.

In PHP:

```
$subject = "Lorem ipsum \x1a dolor sit amet";
$pattern = '/\\x1a/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
echo "First \\x1a offset: ".$matches[0][1]."\n";
```

Or in one of text editor/IDE, that support regular expressions in search/replace. 
For example, http://phped.com/ (one, i'm using) has PCRE-compliant search.